# How to close the display of the file

Tags: python, display

I'm using os.startfile(filename) to open (display) a file. I'm unable to find any command to close the display of this file.

Please, let me know, if there's any corresponding command or function for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs, there is no way -- https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.startfile

> startfile() returns as soon as the associated application is launched.
>   There is no option to wait for the application to close, and no way to
>   retrieve the application’s exit status.

You will need to revert to pywin.

Comment: Well, this means that your script will cease to interact with the application as soon as the file is launched, not that the application can't be killed from within Python.

Comment: Agreed -- that's why I referred him to pywin